# Can't get my reactive variable from graphql local query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to setup a Apollo 3 local state with react. For an unknown reason my query does not work when I try to read a custom type (isAuthenticated query works well). Can you please help me to understand I literaly explored all the documentation and the link on internet about local state management.

Thank you

**cache.js**

```
import { InMemoryCache, makeVar, gql } from '@apollo/client'

export const isAuthenticatedVar = makeVar(!!localStorage.getItem('token'))
export const userVar = makeVar("")

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        isAuthenticated: {
          read() {
            return isAuthenticatedVar()
          }
        },
        user: {
          read() {
            return userVar()
          },
          __typename: 'User',
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export const IS_AUTHENTICATED = gql`
  query IS_AUTHENTICATED {
    isAuthenticated @client
  }
`

export const GET_LOCAL_USER = gql`
  query GET_LOCAL_USER {
    user @client
  }
`
```

**typedej.js**

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'

export const typeDef = gql`

  extend type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    surname: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    phone: String!
    adress: Adress!
    isAdmin: Boolean!
    isCoach: Boolean!
    isManager: Boolean!
  }

  extend type Query {
    isAuthenticated: Boolean!
    user: User!
  }
`

export default typeDef
```

**test.js**

```
const login = (email, password) => {
    const emailLower = email.toLowerCase()
    client.query({
      query: LOGIN,
      variables: { email: emailLower, password: password }
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      localStorage.setItem('token', result.data.login.token)
      localStorage.setItem('userId', result.data.login.user.id)
      
      isAuthenticatedVar(true)
      userVar({ ...result.data.login.user})
      console.log('USER VAR SETUP')
      ///Console.log show that userVar contains an object with all User data
      console.log(userVar())
      var test 
      try{
        //test return NULL object
        test = client.readQuery({ query: GET_LOCAL_USER}).user
      }catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
      console.log('FETCH QUERY userVar')
      console.log(test)

      navigate("/")
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879825/apollo-reactive-variable-are-not-working-when-imported-into-another-file-why

Comment: Not really but thanks. I don't think this is a problem with query update because the boolean query works fine